# How to build cmake-gui with a custom path to qt?

Tags: qt, gcc, compilation, cmake

I am trying to build `cmake-gui` with a custom path and it failed on run:

```
#/opt/dev-tools-4.9/cmake-gui
/opt/dev-tools-4.9/cmake-gui: error while loading shared libraries: libQtGui.so.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

So I want that cmake-gui started to search qtX at /opt/dev-tools-4.9 but it used from a system

```
# strace -f ./cmake-gui
execve("./cmake-gui", ["./cmake-gui"], [/* 24 vars */]) = 0
brk(0)                                  = 0x13ca000
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
mmap(NULL, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7fcfdff0b000
access("/etc/ld.so.preload", R_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=53974, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 53974, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x7fcfdfefd000
close(3)                                = 0
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/tls/x86_64/libQtGui.so.4", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/tls/x86_64", 0x7fffebe47810) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/tls/libQtGui.so.4", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/tls", 0x7fffebe47810) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/x86_64/libQtGui.so.4", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/x86_64", 0x7fffebe47810) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQtGui.so.4", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=12288, ...}) = 0
open("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/tls/x86_64/libQtGui.so.4", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/tls/x86_64", 0x7fffebe47810) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/tls/libQtGui.so.4", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/tls", 0x7fffebe47810) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/x86_64/libQtGui.so.4", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/x86_64", 0x7fffebe47810) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQtGui.so.4", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=32768, ...}) = 0
open("/lib/tls/x86_64/libQtGui.so.4", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/lib/tls/x86_64", 0x7fffebe47810) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/tls/libQtGui.so.4", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/lib/tls", 0x7fffebe47810)        = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/x86_64/libQtGui.so.4", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/lib/x86_64", 0x7fffebe47810)     = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/libQtGui.so.4", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/lib", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
open("/usr/lib/tls/x86_64/libQtGui.so.4", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/usr/lib/tls/x86_64", 0x7fffebe47810) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/tls/libQtGui.so.4", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/usr/lib/tls", 0x7fffebe47810)    = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/x86_64/libQtGui.so.4", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/usr/lib/x86_64", 0x7fffebe47810) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/libQtGui.so.4", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/usr/lib", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
writev(2, [{"./cmake-gui", 11}, {": ", 2}, {"error while loading shared libra"..., 36}, {": ", 2}, {"libQtGui.so.4", 13}, {": ", 2}, {"cannot open shared object file", 30}, {": ", 2}, {"No such file or directory", 25}, {"\n", 1}], 10./cmake-gui: error while loading shared libraries: libQtGui.so.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
) = 124
exit_group(127)                         = ?
+++ exited with 127 +++
```

I found in [LFS](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/svn/general/cmake.html) an example where I can use custom path to qtX:

> If Qt4 and Qt5 are installed in /opt, use source setqt4 or source
>   setqt5 to choose which one will be used to build the Qt-based GUI.

But there isn't those files:

```
~# cd cmake-3.5.2
root:~/cmake-3.5.2# ls |grep set
root:~/cmake-3.5.2#
```

The build of libarchive

```
wget http://www.libarchive.org/downloads/libarchive-3.2.0.tar.gz
tar xzvf  libarchive-3.2.0.tar.gz
./configure --prefix=/opt/dev-tools-4.9 --disable-static && \
make -j $(nproc || grep -c ^processor /proc/cpuinfo|| echo "1") && \
make install
```

the build of cmake 2.8.11

```
wget --no-check-certificate https://cmake.org/files/v2.8/cmake-2.8.11.tar.gz
tar xzvf cmake-2.8.11.tar.gz
./bootstrap --prefix=/opt/dev-tools-4.9   \
  --no-system-libs --qt-gui         && \
  make -j $(nproc || grep -c ^processor /proc/cpuinfo|| echo "1") && \
  make install
```

Comment: Well, you should use `-rpath` linker option during the build, or add the path to libs to LD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variable before execution.

Comment: What do you get if you type `ls /opt | grep qt`? I don't know LFS, but it seems that you have to run `source setqt4` before starting building cmake.

Comment: So it's not a part of cmake?

Answer (score 1):

To adjust rpath for cmake-gui only, you should add something like this to `Source/QtDialog/CMakeLists.txt`, after `add_executable(cmake-gui....)`:

```
set_target_properties(cmake-gui PROPERTIES                
  INSTALL_RPATH "/opt/path/to/qt/shared/libs"
)
```

don't forget to regenerate CMake build files completely. A properly configured build should contain `-Wl,-rpath,<specified-path>` in the linker invocation command in `Source/QtDialog/CMakeFiles/cmake-gui.dir/link.txt`

Note: everything is checked against cmake-3.2.2, but I don't think that other versions of cmake differ significantly in this area.